Discrete-Fourier transform of $$u[-n+2]$$
I'm Trying to Find the fourier transform in discrete time for $$u[-n+2]$$ .
My steps :

Time-Reversal Property : $$ u[(-n+2)] \{\omega\} = u[-(-n+2)] \{-\omega\} = u[n-2] \{-\omega\} $$
Time-Shifting Property : $$ u[n-2] \{-\omega\} =e^{-(-2)j\omega} \cdot u[n] \{-\omega\} = e^{2j\omega} \cdot u[n] \{-\omega\}$$

I know That :
$$ u[n] \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}$$
So by replacing the $\omega$ with $-\omega$ the answer would be :
$$e^{-2j\omega} \cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{j\omega}}$$
My Professor has given the answer as such :
$$
F\{u[-n+2]\}=F\{u[(-n-1)+3]\}=F\left\{z^3 \cdot Z\{u[-n-1]\}\right\}=-e^{+j 3 \omega} \frac{1}{1-e^{-j \omega}}
$$
Which Does not seem to match my answer for some reason .
would appreciate any kind of help !

First of all, you're mixing $\mathcal{Z}$-transform and discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) here. Just because
$$\mathcal{Z}\big\{u[n]\big\}=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$
doesn't mean that
$$\textrm{DTFT}\big\{u[n]\big\}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\tag{2}$$
The correct expression is
$$\textrm{DTFT}\big\{u[n]\big\}=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\tag{3}$$
[Cf. this question and its answers.]
Apart from that, you are right and your professor is wrong. Your professor's expression should look like this:
$$-e^{-3j\omega}\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\tag{4}$$
(note the negative sign in the exponent), because he didn't replace $n$ by $n+3$ but by $n-3$, hence the multiplication with $e^{-3j\omega}$.
Now it's straightforward to show that his (corrected) solution and yours are identical:
$$-\frac{e^{-3j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}=-\frac{e^{-2j\omega}}{e^{j\omega}-1}=\frac{e^{-2j\omega}}{1-e^{j\omega}}\tag{5}$$
With $(3)$ we have
$$\textrm{DTFT}\big\{u[-n+2]\big\}=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{e^{-2j\omega}}{1-e^{j\omega}}\tag{6}$$
